# AWS Lambda - Python : How to pass JSON input to event object in python handler

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function with a lambda handler function.
I want to pass a key via the 'event' object. That key can then be processed via this handler function.

For example I want to pass a JSON input to the lambda handler. The JSON input contain a field 'who'.

This is the code in the lambda function:

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from ' + event.who ) # event.who does not exist even though i pass it via JSON 
    }
```

I created a test event and replaced the Event JSON with the following:

```
{
    "who": "It is me!"
}
```

I am expecting 'who' to be accessible from within the event object inside the lambda_handler.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because how to access items in a Python dictionary including the AWS Lambda `event` could not be a more well covered topic on the site.

Comment: I want to add, that I mean no hostility here at all, and I have not down-voted this question. You may in fact ask and answer your own questions here, and it is great to do so. However, this topic is really well covered and I'm not sure such is needed for posterity. Please take no offense.

Comment: No offense taken. You gave your opinion in a respectful way. I do agree with you that accessing a dictionary item is widely covered. However, this post is informative in terms of learning that the 'event' object in the python handler in AWS lambda is a dictionary, and you can pass key-value pairs to it. This I just learned today. I would like to leave it to the community to decide whether to close this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python we can access the attributes inside a dict this way: dict['attribute']. The 'event' object is a dictionary of key-value pairs. Hence we can use event['who'] to fetch the value of the 'who' attribute.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from ' + event['who'] ) 
    }
```

Comment: No. In python, we access attributes in a dictionary this way, or using the `dict.get` method. We access items in lists using `list[index]`.

Comment: I have edited both the question and the answer based on your feedback.